# What is the "sync" icon next to some Wi-Fi networks?

Tags: wi-fi, settings, notification-icons

When you go to `Menu > Settings > Wireless and network > Wi-Fi Settings` there is the list at the bottom which lists all the detected networks in range or remembered.

The networks in range have the Wi-Fi "signal-strength" icon, and sometimes a lock if it's a secured network. Every now and then though, one or two of the networks will have an icon to the left of the strength, which looks like the "sync" icon from the Accounts screen (the circle with two chasing arrows in it). What does that icon indicate in the context of the Wi-Fi networks?

Running a Galaxy S Captivate with Eclair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The access point supports Wi-Fi Protected Setup (WPS), which allows easier connections to the AP. You can long press the AP to use this feature. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Setup) for more info.

Comment: Ahhh - cool! Thanks for the info... Not knowing what that silly little icon was was driving me crazy every time I looked in the WiFi networks! Now I know - and knowing is half the battle.  B·)